# Clarifying a quote

Tags: reported-speech, quotations

I would like to  quote a shortened version of the following piece of text.

> Explicit minimal times have been given for 2D systems (and lower
>   bounds are given in [7] for the heat equation).
>   Obtaining such expressions, or at least, estimates, is an open problem
>   in larger dimension.

This is how I would like to write it.

*"Obtaining [expressions for explicit minimal times], or at least, estimates,
    is an open problem in larger dimension [than two]."*

Now, I am pretty sure that the first brackets are used correctly. However, I did not find information if the clarification *[than two]* is acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

I can't see much benefit in trying to shorten the quote.  It would be easier to quote fully, or to paraphrase.

> No explicit expression for the minimal time is known for dimensions greater than two [citation].

If a quote is essential, then your solution is correct (the singular "dimension" is odd, but that oddity is present in the source). But the long editorial insertion isn't smooth. So either quote in full or completely paraphrase.